# Python 2 doesn't decode a unicode string correctly (while Python 3 does)

Tags: python, utf-8, python-unicode

I have a unicode string in Python 2, containing a special character that I'm trying to correctly encode and decode.

This is the behaviour in **Python 2**:

```
Python 2.7.15 (default, Nov 27 2018, 21:24:58)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> street = u'Berlin Straße'.encode('utf-8')
>>> street
'Berlin Stra\xc3\x9fe'
>>> street.decode('utf-8')
u'Berlin Stra\xdfe'
```

as you can see it's being decoded as `\xdf` instead of `\xc3\x9f`

In **Python 3** instead I'm not having this problem:

```
Python 3.7.2 (default, Feb 12 2019, 08:15:36)
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> street = u'Berlin Straße'.encode('utf-8')
>>> street
b'Berlin Stra\xc3\x9fe'
>>> street.decode('utf-8')
'Berlin Straße'
```

The "only" difference I notice is that after the encoding, in Python 2 `street` is a `str` while in Python 3 is `bytes`.

Should I convert my Python 2 string to bytes too? If yes, what's the best way of doing that?

p.s: my code needs to be compatible with both Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: These are just differences of representation. In either repl `u'Berlin Straße' == u'Berlin Stra\xdfe'` evaluates to `True`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What you say is right, but I have a test, in Python 2, which fails because it thinks the two things are different. One contains `"Berlin Stra\xc3\x9fe"\r\n'` and the other contain `"Berlin Stra\xdfe"\r\n'`

Comment: `"Berlin Stra\xc3\x9fe"` is UTF-8 (`bytes` in Python 3, `str` in Python 2), `u"Berlin Stra\xdfe"` is unicode (`str` in Python 3, `unicode` in Python 2).  However in Python 2 you can assign the unicode value to a str like `s = 'Berlin Stra\xdfe'`  and end up with a mess.  So it could be that your code isn't strict enough about distinguishing between `str` and `unicode` in Python 2.  But it's not possible to give a definitive answer without seeing code that demonstrates the problem.  Can you share the test and its fixture data, or at least enough to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @snakecharmerb first of all thanks! Your hint (`However in Python 2 you can assign the unicode value to a str like s = 'Berlin Stra\xdfe' and end up with a mess`) made me realise I was trying to compare two different things in my unit test. I was able to use `u'Berlin Straße'` in both places (when I pass the value to the Django model before saving it and when I compare the returned values from a `StreamingHttpResponse` which I was correctly decoding with `rows = [r.decode('utf-8') for r in res.streaming_content]`).